# Decoding Base64 in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have created the following DataFrame:

```
val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(("SnVsZXMgTmV3b25l"), ("Jason Kidd"), ("TXIgUm9uYWxkIE0=")))
val df_data = data.toDF()
val decoded_got = df_data.withColumn("xxx", unbase64(col("value")).cast("String"))
```

And I get the following:

```
+----------------+------------+
|name            |xxx         |
+----------------+------------+
|SnVsZXMgTmV3b25l|Jules Newone|
|Jason Kidd      |%�(���   |
|TXIgUm9uYWxkIE0=|Mr Ronald M |
+----------------+------------+
```

What I want to do is avoid the values of the column name that are not in base 64. For example, get the following `Df`:

```
+----------------+------------+
|name            |xxx         |
+----------------+------------+
|SnVsZXMgTmV3b25l|Jules Newone|
|Jason Kidd      |Jason Kidd  |
|TXIgUm9uYWxkIE0=|Mr Ronald M |
+----------------+------------+
```

I am trying something like this but is not working for me:

```
val regex1 = """^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)?$"""
val check = df_data.withColumn("xxx", when(regex1 matches col("value"), unbase64(col("value"))).otherwise(col("value")))
```

Is there an option in Spark Scala to check if the value is in base64 or how could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether the value is a valid base64 encoded string or not, you can try to decode it and encode it again, you should get the initial value. If not, then it's not a base64 string:

```scala
val decoded_got = df_data.withColumn(
  "xxx",
  when(
    base64(unbase64(col("value"))) === col("value"),
    unbase64(col("value")).cast("string")
  ).otherwise(col("value"))
)

decoded_got.show
//+----------------+------------+
//|           value|         xxx|
//+----------------+------------+
//|SnVsZXMgTmV3b25l|Jules Newone|
//|      Jason Kidd|  Jason Kidd|
//|TXIgUm9uYWxkIE0=| Mr Ronald M|
//+----------------+------------+
```

Comment: There is a logical fallacy here. Base64 is bijective, decoding and encoding always yields the input, by design. Unless of course the input CAN NOT be base64 (contains forbiden chars, is of a wrong length...). You'll catch those allright. But you won't catch collisions between plain text and base64. For ex, the word "together" is a valid base64 string. It encodes to 0xb6881eb617ab, which decodes to "together". Now what almost makes it work is that there's a low probability that 0xb6881eb617ab is a valid UTF (let alone ASCII) byte sequence. Yet, in my book, it's a bug waiting to happen.